# using :ref: in Python docstrings using Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx, docstring

I'm using Sphinx to document a python project, and I'm trying to create a reusable tip to be used in several locations.

Typically, I'll use the following syntax in a python file:

```
"""
.. tip::
    I want this tip to be used in several locations. Why?
        - Save time
        - Work less
"""
```

[image]

Now this works whether I put it at the beginning of the file, right under class definition or right under function definition.

I found [Sphinx's manual](http://sphinx-doc.org/markup/inline.html#role-ref) for :ref:, which suggests to use a label:

```
.. _my_reusable_tip:

.. tip::
   ...
```

And then call this tip with `` :ref:`my_reusable_tip` `` anywhere I want.
The manual states that 'it works across files, when section headings are changed, and for all builders that support cross-references'

The thing is, it doesn't matter in which .py file in the project I write the label and tip definition, the `` :ref:`my_reusable_tip` `` just displays 'my_reusable_tip', and not the tip itself.

What I'm using to build the documentation is

```
sphinx-apidoc -f -F -o
make html
```

I'm pretty sure my logic is flawed in some way, but I can't figure out why.
I know that Sphinx searches the project for reStructuredText and renders it if it can, but I think I'm missing something here.

- I tried to add this label in a seperate .py file enclosed in """, and in a separate .txt file without enclosed """.
- I tried creating an .rst file with the label definition and rebuild the html documentation.

What am I missing here?

Python 3.4.3 BTW.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just using reStructuredText directive

```
.. include:: ./my_reusable_tip.txt
```

in your rst files?

Comment: That actually works....! Thanks! Is there a way to create a "global" include? So all other .srt files will inherit from it? Or maybe a value in conf.py that will add the line to all .srt files? I tried copying the .txt file to _templates, that didn't work. Neither did adding the include line to index.srt

Answer (score 3):

In sphinx, a `:ref:` is simply a more robust way of linking (or referencing) another part of the document.  Thus, your use of `:ref:` will simply provide a hyperlink to the label.

It is not a way of *substituting* or expanding a block.

[Inline substitutions](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/user/rst/quickref.html#substitution-references-and-definitions) are available using using `|...|`, however an inline substitution cannot be used to substitute a block as you seem to require.

RestructuredText is not a template language, and thus doesn't provide macro like facilities.  In the event you need it, an alternative solution is to use a template library such as `mako` or `jinja` to deal with this kind of issue.

Comment: Hmm, that's unfortunate, but understandable. I think jinja is the way to go. Thanks for taking the time to answer